# Meson build error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mesonbuild'"

Tags: drivers

While trying to download *Zathura* with **Meson**, I stumbled across an error;

```
[0/1] Installing files.
Installation failed due to insufficient permissions.
Attempting to use polkit to gain elevated privileges...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dbizdfvy/.local/bin/meson", line 7, in <module>
    from mesonbuild.mesonmain import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mesonbuild'
FAILED: meson-install 
/home/dbizdfvy/.local/bin/meson install --no-rebuild
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I've downloaded Meson's latest build and made sure that every dependencies required are all there.I'm not really sure what's happening as I'm still new to Linux.

Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Faced the same issue compiling Mesa from sources.

Have found this answer: https://gitmemory.com/issue/MusicPlayerDaemon/MPD/546/490849388

The reason of this issue:

> You installed Meson in a user's home directory, and another user (i.e. root) can't use that Meson installation. Either root also needs to install Meson in his home directory, or you install it in the system folders for all users.

Though the solution is to install Meson as root:

```
# pip3 install meson
```